# Curve not shown completely after numerical resolution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, output

I'm having an output problem with the following code :

```
fl := NDSolve[{
    q''[t] == -(p'[t]^2 - (3/4) (p[t]^2 - 4)^2) q[t],
    q[t] p''[t] == - 3 q'[t] p'[t] - q[t] 3 (p[t]^2 - 4) p[t],

    q[0] == 1, q'[0] == 1, p[0] == 1, p'[0] == 0

    }, {q, p}, {t, -50, 50},
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"
]

T1 := (q /. fl)[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
T2 := (q /. fl)[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]
Evaluate[p[T1] /. fl]
Evaluate[p[T2] /. fl]

Plot[Evaluate[p[t] /. fl], {t, T1, T2}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

The plot appears to show only the main part of the curve, but some parts are missing on its extremities.  The evaluation at *min time* **T1** and *max time* **T2** shows that the curve should continue up to approx **p[T1] = 16** and **p[T2] = 15.68**.  The plot ends the curve at approx values **p = 8.5** and **p = 9.1**.  The **PlotRange -> All** directive doesn't seem to help here.  Why ?  How to show the full curve up to its extremities ?

Comment: `[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]` can be replaced with `[[1,1,1,1]]`

Comment: @Feyre, thanks for the trick.  It works, but doesn't change my output problem.

Comment: I found an older question on the same topic that already covers both `ListLinePlot` and `ParametricPlot` so I am marking this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a simple trick :  to use **ParametricPlot**, instead of **Plot** :

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{t, p[t]} /. fl], {t, T1, T2}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

Now, is there a drawback with this solution ?

Comment: I'd add `, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio`

Comment: Off hand I don't know why `ParametricPlot` includes the end points and `Plot` does not.  Clearly that helps here but conceivably that behavior may change between versions.  Manual points (`Table` etc.) has the advantage of never changing.  (And +1 for sharing your solution of course.)

Answer (score 1):

The slope approaching T1 and T2 is extreme.  By default the plot mesh doesn't get close enough to these values to show the limits.  I recommend using [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) on a series of directly calculated points:

```
foo = First[p[t] /. fl];

ListLinePlot[
 Table[{t, foo}, {t, T1, T2, (T2 - T1)/1000}]
 , PlotRange -> All
 , Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Ufortunately, that would complicate a lot my full code (which was simplified to show the problem here).  So there is no other way to get the full curve, using a standard Plot, with some options ?

Comment: @Cham If you describe *why* this would complicate your full code I might be able to suggest an improvement.  I'll see if I can force `Plot` to give you want you want however.

Comment: I just found a simple trick :  use **ParametricPlot** !  I'll post an answer !  ;-)